# How to display array value to table different row's column with the same <td> selector

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a table with add button to create new row, each row has 3 columns name quantity, unit price and total.. I want to display the product of every (quantity * unit price) to the total column everytime I press the total button.

```
$(document).on('click','#equals',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantity = [];
    var unitPrice = [];
    // var total = [];

    $('.quantity').each(function(){
        quantity.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('.unit-price').each(function(){
        unitPrice.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(quantity);
    console.log(unitPrice);

    var product = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++){
       product = quantity.map((a, i) => a * unitPrice[i]);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < product.length; i++){
       $('.total').each(function(){
            $('.total').text(product);
        });
    }

    console.log('Product of every quantity * unit price of every row: ', product);
```

Comment: quantity and unit price columns is content editable i input value to each column then i pressed the total button to display the value of quantity * unit price

Comment: Share your html